# Microsoft Graph API - file invite endpoint not working suddenly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

**Issue**: While Inviting user/Add permission to Item,Getting 400 with message - The request is malformed or incorrect. This was worked earlier and stopped working now.

**Article:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_invite

**Post URL :**

```
POST /v1.0/me/drive/items/01B6CXZGZ7RGHIXZBXKNCZB747AVB52EQ2/invite HTTP/1.1 
Host: graph.microsoft.com 
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 213 
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Accept: application/json, text/plain, / 
Origin: https://developer.microsoft.com
```

**Payload :**

```
{ 
    "recipients": [{ "email": "ryan@contoso.com" }],
    "message": "Here's the file that we're collaborating on.", 
    "requireSignIn": false, 
    "sendInvitation": true, 
    "roles": [ "read" ]
}
```

**Response:**

```
{ 
    "error": { 
        "code": "invalidRequest", 
        "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.", 
        "innerError": { 
            "request-id": "c8a02a02-299c-4ace-8e40-dbd6f830d9ba", 
            "date": "2018-05-17T11:38:00"
        }
    }
}
```

PD: We also have tested the beta version of the graph api, and the response is the same than with the v1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems after some days without working, this afternoon they have restored the service and now it works again