# Microsoft Graph API - Invite endpoint returning Bad request every time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to share SharePoint directory so specific user invite the invite API endpoint from Microsoft Graph : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite

Every time I do the request, I'm receiving a "400 - Bad request" response.

Here is my request:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/***/drives/***/items/***/invite`

Here is the payload:

```
{
    "requireSignIn": true,
    "sendInvitation": false,
    "roles": [
        "read"
    ],
    "recipients": [
        {
            "email": "***@***.***"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Error in Graph Explorer]

It used to work perfectly.

Comment: I did not see the api you provided in the document, try to change it to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/***/drive/items/***/invite`

Comment: I need to select the right drive, it used to work perfectly with the endpoint I provided

Comment: I have tried using the same call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{driveid}/Items/{itemid}/invite` and gave the payload as `{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "email": "mmamamamamamaska@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "requireSignIn": true,
  "sendInvitation": false,
  "roles": [ "read" ]
}`
Use this data exactly and give a try. It worked for me.

Comment: I still have the same issue with your payload.
When doing a GET request on `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{driveid}/Items/{itemid}`, I have the information of my directory so it exists.

Comment: Specify content-type as application/json as shown in this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and give a try.

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft Graph Explorer to do the test. I added the content-type header, but same issue.

Comment: Please check if the item you are using is a driveitem. Looks like a temporary issue according to this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392291/microsoft-graph-api-file-invite-endpoint-not-working-suddenly).

Comment: The thread you mentioned is from 2018.
It's a driveitem, i can access it from SharePoint. I don't know how to get the type using Graph API.

Comment: Please file a service request with microsoft support as it looks like a backend issue.